# ¿Como rellenar una matriz con los caracteres de un texto ingresado? (Java)

Tags: java, array, string, matrices, caracteres

Buen dia, ocupo rellenar una matriz con los caracteres de un texto ingresado por el usuario, en este caso el texto posee una longitud de 20 caracteres, por lo que he creado una matriz de 4x5 para que cada caracter se vaya guardando en orden en cada indice de la matriz, por ejemplo en este caso la palabra ingresada es "laburadores de bus 1"

[image: Esta imagen muestra la forma en que quiero que se aloje el texto en la matriz]

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese un texto: ");
        String textoIngresado = sc.nextLine();

        char[][] AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto = new char[4][5];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){//Ciclo for para rellenar la matriz
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++){
                AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j] = textoIngresado.charAt(j);//Aqui esta mi problema
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){//Ciclo for para mostrar la matriz
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.print(AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Mi problema esta en el primer ciclo for, ya que en la parte de charAt el contador de indices solo llegaría hasta j, y j solo tiene recorrido hasta 5, y yo necesito que tenga un indice que llegue hasta 20
que es la longitud del texto para que de tal manera se guarden todos los caracteres del texto en la matriz pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, ya intente anidar otro tercer ciclo for con el contador hasta 20 pero no obtengo ningún resultado favorable, de antemano gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo `i` y `j`, que son los índices de tu matriz, puedes saber perfectamente qué posición del texto tienes que utilizar, que es: `j + i * 5`.

Por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) {
        AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j] = textoIngresado.charAt(j + i * 5);
    } 
}
```

Para visualizarlo mejor, puedes pensarlo 'al revés'. Este es el resultado que quieres obtener:

```
   j =   0 1 2 3 4

i = 0    l a b u r 
    1    a d o r e 
    2    s   d e   
    3    b u s   1
```

El índice `j` te permite moverte horizontalmente, mientras que el `i` te permite saltar de línea.

Cada vez que saltas de línea estás dejando atrás 5 caracteres (para cada línea). Y esto es básicamente lo que quiere decir la expresión `j + i * 5`:

Avanzo `j` posiciones + 5 posiciones por el número de líneas `i` que haya avanzado.

Obviamente, esto con la particularidad de que los índices empiezan en 0.

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://ideone.com/YxmeOu)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable contador a la que se sume 1 en cada iteración. Así recorrerías toda la cadena de texto.

```
int contador = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
  for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) {
     AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j] = textoIngresado.charAt(contador);
     contador++;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solución añadir un contador:

```
String textoIngresado = "laburadores de bus 1";
        int cont = 0;//Declaras un contador (Entero)
        char[][] AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto = new char[4][5];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){//Ciclo for para rellenar la matriz
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++){
                AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j] = textoIngresado.charAt(cont);//Aqui esta mi problema
                cont++;//Después de ingresar la posición cero le vas sumando uno por vuelta el problema de usar la variable j es 
                //que siempre vuelve a comenzar en cero por eso imprime siempre los mismos cinco caracteres
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){//Ciclo for para mostrar la matriz
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.print(AquiAlmacenoLosCaracteresDelTexto[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```